# How to Enter Value in table, if the table cells as Document F#

Tags: f#, flaui

Want to enter value in table, followed the Hierarchy that is tree up to the table but not able select and edit the value inside the table, Found by Flaui that cell refers as document.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aATMW.png)
Table is having the Name and AutomationId.
The yellow Highlighted one refer as Document and all the cell refers as Document only.
Then How to edit that value in the table